# Dynamically Build SQL string in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a query called `FilingHeaderQry` in MS Access.

Due to some crosstab joins, the number of columns are constantly changing based on the crosstab and a lot are duplicated.

I would like to use some VBA to dynamically build the `select` statement that will call only the columns that **don't** end with `'ELIM'`.

For example, `FilingHeaderQry` will have the following columns:

```
State, Product, Date, Count, StateElim, ProductElim, DateElim, Sum
```

I would like the `select` statement to be:

```
Select State, Product, Date, Count, Sum
from FilingHeaderQry
```

Comment: Please post the SQL of your crosstab as it seems like *Count*, *Sum*, and other non-Elim are not part of the dynamic part of query.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attempting to dynamically build a `select` statement using VBA, a far easier solution would be to revise the selection criteria of your crosstab query such that columns ending with `Elim` are not included in the output.

For example, something along the lines of:

```
TRANSFORM <AggregateFunction>(YourTable.ValueField) AS CrossTabValue
SELECT YourTable.RowField
FROM YourTable
WHERE YourTable.ColumnField NOT LIKE '*Elim'
GROUP BY YourTable.RowField
PIVOT YourTable.ColumnField
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I explained this well enough. I have FilingHeaderQry that joins to List_Crosstab. I kept the columns in the crosstab so that I could use them as the join criteria with FilingHeaderQry. The issue is that since the columns in the crosstab can change, I could only do a select *. FilingHeaderQry looks something like this:Select State, Product, Date, Location, crosstab.* from FilingHeaderQry FHQ left join crosstab on FHQ.State = crosstab.State and FHQ.Product = crosstab.Product

Comment: I think I figured it out. I combined FilingHeaderQry and another query via a join and then did the pivot on those two. That eliminated the column duplication issue.